# ImportError while performing pip install

Tags: python, pip, installation, setuptools

While in my virtual environment, i'm trying to perform 'pip install .' with a setup.py such as :

```
from setuptools import setup
import pbr

... some functions ...

setup(
    name='example',
    setup_requires=['pbr'],
    py_modules=['example'],

    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        example=example:main
    ''',
)
```

The thing is that i get the following error **ImportError: No module named pbr**

This seems quite legit as i didn't install pbr in my virtual environment BUT i thought that specifying 'setup_requires' would do the trick ... :/

Does someone understand why this does not work and knows how to fix it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The script does `import pbr` before running `setup()` so `setup()` was not given a chance to install `pbr`.

The fix is to not import `pbr` before running `setup()`. See https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/using.html:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr'],
    pbr=True,
)
```